# Slow Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, performance, firebase-realtime-database, benchmarking

I am using Firebase Realtime Database in my Python backend for session management where the key and value are both ~7 character strings, and AWS S3 for other tasks. Upon preliminary benchmarking, though, it looks like Firebase doesn't have the promised speed.

```
sessions_ref = firebase_db.reference('sessions/')                   
start_time = time.perf_counter()
sessions_ref.child('182746').get()
print(time.perf_counter() - start_time)`


0.2823506660060957
```

That's in seconds. At this rate, reading the entire sessions lookup table (~2000 key-value pairs) from S3 into a python dictionary and then reading the single value of interest would be quicker!

Is there some inefficiency in the code above?

Answer (score 0):

If that's the only code in the entire program that you're benchmarking, then your timing is also showing the cost of establishing the websocket to the database server.  You pay this overhead once for every new client app object, and that's going to happen every time you launch the program. It's also an unavoidable cost.

What you should do is also measure the time of *additional* queries in the same program with the same initialized app, after the first one that establishes the connection. Those queries will reuse the existing websocket, and you will see much lower query times.

Also it's not clear what you mean by "promised speed". The speed of a query is going to depend on many things, including the quality of your internet connection, and the closeness of the machine running the code to the database server.  There is a lot of room for variance there.  If your application must have low latency queries, then it's beneficial to both:

1. Move your code closer to the data.
2. Move the data closer to the code by [selecting the best location](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations) for the database.

There is nothing terribly "slow" about Firebase Realtime Database when reading a single key.  The thing that ends up being slow is the connection between the client and the database.